# Pinescript: Normalized MACD does not have a V5 version

Tags: pine-script

A lot of grammar can't be found online.
Any help anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.
it keeps throwing the error.

> Could not find function or function reference 'lowest'.

```
study("Normalized MACD",shorttitle='N MACD')
sma = input(12,title='Fast MA')
lma = input(21,title='Slow MA')
tsp = input(9,title='Trigger')
np = input(50,title='Normalize')
h=input(true,title='Histogram')
docol = input(false,title="Color Change")
dofill=input(false,title="Fill")
type = input(1,minval=1,maxval=3,title="1=Ema, 2=Wma, 3=Sma")

sh = type == 1 ? ema(close,sma)  
 : type == 2 ? wma(close, sma)
 : sma(close, sma)

lon=type == 1 ? ema(close,lma) 
 : type == 2 ? wma(close, lma)
 : sma(close, lma)

ratio = min(sh,lon)/max(sh,lon)
Mac = (iff(sh>lon,2-ratio,ratio)-1)
MacNorm = ((Mac-lowest(Mac, np)) /(highest(Mac, np)-lowest(Mac, np)+.000001)*2)- 1
MacNorm2 = iff(np<2,Mac,MacNorm)
Trigger = wma(MacNorm2, tsp)
Hist = (MacNorm2-Trigger)
Hist2 = Hist>1?1:Hist<-1?-1:Hist
swap=Hist2>Hist2[1]?green:red
swap2 = docol ? MacNorm2 > MacNorm2[1] ? #0094FF : #FF006E : red
plot(h?Hist2:na,color=swap,style=columns,title='Hist',histbase=0)
plot(MacNorm2,color=swap2,title='MacNorm')
plot(dofill?MacNorm2:na,color=MacNorm2>0?green:red,style=columns)
plot(Trigger,color=yellow,title='Trigger')
hline(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

A few problems:

- Colors in version 4 and later converted to the `color.` namespace ie. `red` became `color.red` etc.
- Plots styles moved to the `plot.style_` namespace ie. `columns` became `plot.style_columns`
- `highest()` and `lowest()` moved to the `ta.` namespace in version 5 ie. they became `ta.highest()`.

All of the info can be found online. The [reference manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/) and the [user manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/Introduction.html) will hold all of the information you need, and for specific changes that occurred in version 5, the [migration guide](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/index.html#migration-guides) is your ticket.

There is also the [auto converter](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_5.html#v4-to-v5-converter), which will automatically upgrade scripts from v3 to v4 and again from v4 to v5.

Here is the converted code for you this time, while you do some reading for the next one.

```
//@version=5
indicator('Normalized MACD', shorttitle='N MACD')
sma = input(12, title='Fast MA')
lma = input(21, title='Slow MA')
tsp = input(9, title='Trigger')
np = input(50, title='Normalize')
h = input(true, title='Histogram')
docol = input(false, title='Color Change')
dofill = input(false, title='Fill')
type = input.int(1, minval=1, maxval=3, title='1=Ema, 2=Wma, 3=Sma')

sh = type == 1 ? ta.ema(close, sma) : type == 2 ? ta.wma(close, sma) : ta.sma(close, sma)

lon = type == 1 ? ta.ema(close, lma) : type == 2 ? ta.wma(close, lma) : ta.sma(close, lma)

ratio = math.min(sh, lon) / math.max(sh, lon)
Mac = (sh > lon ? 2 - ratio : ratio) - 1
MacNorm = (Mac - ta.lowest(Mac, np)) / (ta.highest(Mac, np) - ta.lowest(Mac, np) + .000001) * 2 - 1
MacNorm2 = np < 2 ? Mac : MacNorm
Trigger = ta.wma(MacNorm2, tsp)
Hist = MacNorm2 - Trigger
Hist2 = Hist > 1 ? 1 : Hist < -1 ? -1 : Hist
swap = Hist2 > Hist2[1] ? color.green : color.red
swap2 = docol ? MacNorm2 > MacNorm2[1] ? #0094FF : #FF006E : color.red
plot(h ? Hist2 : na, color=swap, style=plot.style_columns, title='Hist', histbase=0)
plot(MacNorm2, color=swap2, title='MacNorm')
plot(dofill ? MacNorm2 : na, color=MacNorm2 > 0 ? color.green : color.red, style=plot.style_columns)
plot(Trigger, color=color.new(color.yellow, 0), title='Trigger')
hline(0)
```

Cheers and best of luck with your trading and coding